# Using static automapper in C# asp.net performance practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

In advance, I apologize if this question has been answered already somewhere else; But I've been finding a lot of mixed results on the matter.

I'm using:

- .net Framework 4.6.1
- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6
- AutoMapper 6.2.2
- EntityFramework 6.2.0

I'm quite new to both ASP.net and C# and lately I've become a fan of the AutoMapper package. I've mostly been using it to convert my Entities I get from my `ApplicationDbContext` to my `DTO`'s (Data Transfer Objects) or `ViewModel`'s.

I now use this setup in my applications to initialize and use the `Mapper` in my `Controller`'s:

*Global.asax.cs*

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure);

        // Other configuration for MVC application...
    }
}
```

*AutoMapperConfiguration.cs*

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure(IMapperConfigurationExpression config)
    {
        config.CreateMap<Post, Post.DetailsViewModel>().ForMember(post => post.CanEdit, cfg => cfg.ResolveUsing((src, dst, arg3, context) => context.Options.Items["UserId"]?.ToString() == src.UserId));
    }
}
```

*PostsController.cs and Post.cs*

```
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);

        if (post == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(Mapper.Map<Post.DetailsViewModel>(post, options => options.Items["UserId"] = User.Identity?.GetUserId()));
    }
}


// Post.cs

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime PostedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public class DetailsViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// A value indicating whether the current logged in user can edit the model
        /// </summary>
        public bool CanEdit { get; set; }

        public DateTime PostedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Code summary**

I am configuring my `Mapper` in a static class (`AutoMapperConfiguration`) that contains a `Config` method which is invoked from the `Global.asax.cs` file and maps the required classes.

Then, in my `Controller` I use the static method `Mapper.Map` to map my `Post` to it's `DetailsViewModel`.

**The question**

How does this usage of AutoMapper (via static method `Mapper.Map`) impact performance, and is there a better way to do this?

*Some clarifications:*

For example: What if I get 100 requests per second on different controller actions; As far as I know every request will have a separate thread but will access the same memory for the `Mapper.Map` method (if I am correct). Which - to my knowledge - means performance will be impacted severely.

*A question I have already looked at but got mixed results from:*

[Non-static AutoMapper and ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319320/non-static-automapper-and-asp-net-mvc) -> [Where to place AutoMapper.CreateMaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825244/where-to-place-automapper-createmaps)

Please correct me if I'm wrong on any of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does this usage of AutoMapper (via static method Mapper.Map) impact performance, and is there a better way to do this?

Your usage of AutoMapper is correct. Initialization at the application startup is a best practice to respect. By calling `Mapper.Initialize` you are initializing a mapper which is an static instance of `IMapper` interface (accessible through `Mapper.Instance` static property). When using the static members from `Mapper` class you are dealing with `Mapper.Instance` and it is the same instance for all objects into the same `AppDomain`. You will not impact performance as long as long you're into the same `AppDomain` and not doing some time consuming in your mapping configuration (someone may put some business logic or time consuming logic into `AfterMap`, `BeforeMap`, `ResolveUsing`, `MapFrom` etc.).

> What if I get 100 requests per second on different controller actions;
>   As far as I know every request will have a separate thread but will
>   access the same memory for the Mapper.Map method (if I am correct).
>   Which - to my knowledge - means performance will be impacted severely.

Your application use one instance of `AppDomain`, each request will got a new thread but that thread will run in the same `AppDomain` that started your application, the one that executed the `Application_Start` method and finally you'll get the same instance of `Mapper.Instance` so your configuration's plan will only be compiled and cached when the first request arrive. Only the first request will be impacted not the following. Other requests will use the cached configuration's plan. So no performance impact as long as you're in the same `AppDomain` and not using some time consuming logic into custom mapping alternative that AutoMapper allows you to do.

Also AutoMapper comes with some cnfigurations that can be activated or deactivated and gain performance.

### Explicit compilation

As I already said, the first request that uses mapping will compile your configuration's plan. As AutoMapper's [documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html?highlight=CompileMappings()%3B#configuration-compilation) says:

> Because expression compilation can be a bit resource intensive, AutoMapper lazily compiles the type map plans on first map. However, this  behavior is not always desirable, so you can tell AutoMapper to compile its mappings directly.
>   For a few hundred mappings, this may take a couple of seconds.

You can explicitly compile the plan by doing this just after your mapping configuration:

```
Mapper.Configuration.CompileMappings();
```

I use this and combine it with application "warming" where my application is started automatically instead of waiting for the first request to do mapping and compiles my configuration's plan. You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355383/webapi-application-start-will-not-fire-until-web-page-is-loaded-or-signalr-reque/50358193#50358193) for how to enable that feature.

### Inline mapping

With 6.2.0, AutoMapper came with a new feature which is called [inline mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html) which allow you to create a type map on the fly instead of configuring them through the call of `Mapper.Initialize` method. Because an inline mapping is created on the fly so they are compiled at that time so the gain you're looking for explicitly compiling your plan does not help a lot. So what I do in my projects, I deactivate this feature so anyone can't inadvertisely used it. To deactivate it, you do this:

```
cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = false;
```

---

#### Edit 26/02/2019

AutoMapper creator just added a blog post today (26/02/2019) about [AutoMapper Usage Guidelines](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/). Must read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you, but i've updated the AutoMapper to version 8.1.0 and the performance is better. I've seen that performance was corrected on version 7.0.0 but in the latest version can be better. Depends on your implementation the impact of update is minimal.